# Windows Task Scheduler - tasks not actually running

Tags: scheduled-tasks

We have about 6 Windows Servers (2016-2019). Some are on a domain, some are not. The servers on the domain run tasks from a dedicated "DOMAIN\TaskScheduler" domain account. The servers not on the domain run tasks using the local admin. Randomly, we find out that even though a task says it ran (Last Run Time = today's date), it actually did not. In order for it to start doing its job, we need to either disable/enable it, and sometimes even need to modify the trigger to make it start one minute later or earlier. Logs say they ran fine. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot why this is happening?

Comment: If the Task Scheduler says that the task was run, then it was run and failed in some way. You most likely need to debug the task itself.

Comment: What is in the Event Log?